# Can't run a bash script from docker-compose command in mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, bash, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to run a bash script in a mongo db container on start up, so i have a script file and i put the location of the script file in the command argument of my docker-compose, like so:

```
mongo1:
container_name: mongo1
image: mongo:4.4
volumes:
  - ~/mongors/data1:/data/db
  - ./rs-init.sh:/scripts/rs-init.sh
networks:
  - mongors-network
ports:
  - 27021:27017
links:
  - mongo2
  - mongo3
restart: always
entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "dbrs" ]
command: /scripts/rs-init.sh
```

But when i do docker-compose up, it says this command is invalid, then gives me all the options for mongodb commands:

```
Invalid command: /scripts/rs-init.sh
 Options:
   --networkMessageCompressors arg (=snappy,zstd,zlib)
                                         Comma-separated list of compressors to
                                         use for network messages

 General options:
   -h [ --help ]                         Show this usage information
   --version                             Show version information
   -f [ --config ] arg                   Configuration file specifying
```

How do i run this bash script in the container on startup?

Comment: From the [mongo dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo): "*When a container is started for the first time it will execute files with extensions `.sh` and `.js` that are found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`.*"

Answer (score 0):

To understand the error, you need to understand the relationship between `command` and `entrypoint`: the value of `command` is provided as an argument to whatever is defined in `entrypoint`, so given this:

```
entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "dbrs" ]
command: /scripts/rs-init.sh
```

You are trying to run the command line:

```
/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet dbrs /scripts/rs-init.sh
```

...which doesn't make any sense; `/scripts/rs-init.sh` isn't a valid argument to the `mongod` command.

---

As @Turing85 points out in a comment, the correct solution in this case is to take advantage of the behavior built into the `mongo` container: it looks for initialization files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. For this to work, you need to *not* specify your own `entrypoint` in your `docker-compose.yaml` (because doing so overrides the `ENTRYPOINT` baked into the container image):

```
mongo1:
  container_name: mongo1
  image: mongo:4.4
  volumes:
    - ~/mongors/data1:/data/db
    - ./rs-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/rs-init.sh
  networks:
    - mongors-network
  ports:
    - 27021:27017
  restart: always
```

---

Unrelated to your question: You should also remove the `links` section from your `docker-compose.yaml` file; the use of `links` has been deprecated for years (because it is fragile in the event that one of the linked containers restarts); you can just refer to other containers in your compose file by name.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` in the same container run, the CMD is passed to the ENTRYPOINT as a parameter and you end up only having a single, combined command being executed. In your case, the command ends up being

```
/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet dbrs /scripts/rs-init.sh
```

and Mongo complains that it doesn't understand the last parameter.

Instead, you can change your entrypoint to a shell and run the 2 commands you want by concatenating them with `&&`, like this

```
entrypoint: ["/bin/bash"]
command: -c '/scripts/rs-init.sh && docker-entrypoint.sh mongod'
```

I've chosen to start Mongo with the 'normal' startup script. If you prefer your existing way of doing it (`/usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet dbrs`), you should be able to use that instead.

As a note, you should only do this if you want the script to run *every* time you start the container. If you want the script to only run when you're initializing a new database (i.e. the `/data/db` volume mount is empty), then you should use the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory as @Turing85 and @larsks suggest. But as I read your post, you want to run it every time.